# Fail Jenkins-Invoked Grunt build if tests focused/skipped

Tags: jenkins, gruntjs, jasmine, continuous-integration, protractor

Is it possible to fail a Grunt build running Jasmine tests via Karma and Protractor if any of them are skipped?

A focused test just sneaked into committed code, and I'd like to prevent this from giving false positives in CI.

Answer (score 1):

We've solved that with `ESLint` and [`eslint-plugin-jasmine` plugin](https://github.com/tlvince/eslint-plugin-jasmine) that issues an error if there are *focused or disabled test cases left*. Sample error:

```
/Users/user/job/company/prj/test/e2e/specs/login/login.view.spec.js
28:1   error  Unexpected fdescribe                 jasmine/no-focused-tests
```

We are also using [`pre-git`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pre-git) that installs a pre-commit hook triggering `ESLint` to run.